# Question about serve Angular static files with ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: angular, api, static, asp.net-core-6.0, serve

I'm trying to serve static Angular files with ASP.NET Core 6. My idea is to build a REST API where I will have route for example `/app` and when user is authenticated, I will redirect him to `/app` and send to him the Angular app.

Is that possible? The benefit what I want is to run everything in one server, with SSR landing, privacy, terms page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I find a solution but I'm not sure if that is right. I created "ASP.NET" application, and on route "/app" I just return blank html with scripts from my Angular "dist" folder. I'm junior, and I just want to know if I'm on the right way?